# An outer measure is countable-additive on the measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given an outer measure $\mu^*$, i'm trying to prove that for any set $E$, and a countable number of distinct (pairwise) $\mu^*$-measurable sets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$:

$$\mu^*\left(E \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\right)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu^*\left(E\cap A_i\right)$$

One inequality is obvious thanks to sub-additivity, but i'm having troubles with the other.

I figured out that i could maybe show

$$\mu^*\left(E \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\right)\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \mu^*\left(E\cap A_i\right)$$

and then take the limit.

For that I would need to show only that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left( E\cap A_i\right)=\mu^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E\cap A_i\right)= \mu^*\left(E \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)\right)$$

If i'm right and all of this is really necessary, I guess that i'd need to prove that:

1. for finite number of measurable subsets, the union is measurable
2. finite-additivity for measurable sets.

I managed to prove the first for my outer measure $\mu^*$, but about the second - it is easy to show that for measurable subsets, but after doing all that I realised that $E \cap A_i $ does not have to be measurable itself.

Is anything of what I did useful to prove what I wanted?
How can I complete, or what steps should I take in order to prove it differently?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can prove that your outer measure $\mu^*$ is finite-additive, then this would actually imply that it is a measure and thus completely additive. Since your outer measure seems to be non specific, this might be difficult to show?

Comment: @user128779 I didn't prove that $\mu^*$ is finite-additive, only that it is finite-additive for measureable sets, which I believe is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the finite case with finite induction on $n$. It works because the disjoint union is monotone increasing in terms of containment as $n$ increases. For the infinite case observe that for all $n$
$$
E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E\cap A_k\supseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^nE\cap A_k
$$
so that 
$$
\mu^*(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu^*(E\cap A_k)\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\mu^*(E\cap A_k).
$$
Since the LHS doesn't involve $n$, taking the limit finishes the proof!

---

More detail:

First I accidentally reversed the set names, see my edits above. Second, for the finite case, since each $A_k$ is measurable then for any set $E$ we have by induction:
$$\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)&=\mu^*((E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)\cap A_n)+\mu^*((E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k)\cap A^C_n)\\
&=\mu^*(E\cap A_n)+\mu^*(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k)\\
&=\mu^*(E\cap A_n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mu^*(E\cap A_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu^*(E\cap A_k)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I actually didn't quite understand what you did here.
For starters, What do you mean by "the finite case"? It would probably help me understand the rest parts I did not understand.
Thanks!

Comment: And to be more specific, I had problem understanding how you moved from the first row of equations to the second.
You used countable-additivity, which does not hold for outer measures. Or did you use some other reasoning that I could not see?

Comment: See my edits above. The second row is just the first row with the outer measure applied.

Comment: This has been most helpful. Although it did make me feel stupid for all the hard work I gave so far, which was pretty much irrelevant.
Thanks :))

Comment: I have spent a lot of time getting this sorted. Welcome to the club!

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: I guess there's a mistake in the second line. Suggestion: $\mu^*(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)\geq\mu^*(E\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu^*(E\cap A_k)$

Answer (score 1):

If $m^*\left(A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right) = \infty$, the reserve inequality holds trivially.
If $m^*\left(A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right) < \infty$, we can find a $G_\delta$ set $G$ that contains $A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ and satisfies
$$
m^*(G) = m^*\left(A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)
$$
Since $G$ is measurable, we have
\begin{align*}
    m^*\left(A \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right) &= m^*(G) \\
    &\geq m^*\left(G \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right) \\
    &= m^*\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (G \cap E_k)\right) \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(G\cap E_k) \\
    &\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(A\cap E_k)
\end{align*}
where the fourth line follows because $G \cap E_k$ is measurable for all $k$ and the inequalities follow from the monotonicity of outer measure.