# Algebras: Finite Additivity $\implies$ Countable Additivity (Idea?)

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given an algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Consider a set function $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{R}_+$:

Then countable additivity follows from finite additivity:
$$\mu(A+B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)\implies\mu(A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)$$

Can you explain the idea behind the proof?
*(I always forget the precise steps probably because I haven't understand it yet.)*

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000608/an-outer-measure-is-countable-additive-on-the-measureable-sets/1000639#1000639

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is something missing in yiur question.

To see this, consider the algebra(!) of all subsets $A \subset \Bbb{N}$ which are finite or for which $A^c$ is finite.

Define $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is finite and $\mu(A)=1$ otherwise. It is easy to verify that $\mu$ is finitely additive, but not countably additive.

Comment: Ah I'm missing monotony ...let me add it to the assumptions!

Comment: But for algebras monotony follows from additivity. So there must be a flaw somewhere in your example?

Comment: $\mu$ is monotone. If $A \subset B$ and $\mu(A) \not\leq \mu(B)$ (for contradiction), then $\mu(A)=1$ and $\mu(B)=0$, which (by definition) yields that $B$ is finite, so that $A\subset B$ is also finite, a contradiction to $\mu(A)=1$. BTW: I did not downvote.

Comment: Ah and yes it needs more to be automatically countably additive - something like continuity?

Comment: Ya I guess there's somebody voting down on all of my threads (c'est la vie).

Comment: Continuity from below will do the trick, i.e. if $B =\bigcup B_n$ (all contained in the algebra) with $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$, then $\mu(B_n)\to \mu(B)$. This (together with additivity) suffices for countable additivity, the proof is not really difficult. If the measure is finite, then continuity from above is also enough. There is also some topological condition one can impose, iirc, that is if $\mu$ is inner regular (and finite) on the algebra, this will also suffice.