# Outer measure proof for sets.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

This problem is for my intro to real analysis class and I'm really struggling with some of the involved concepts with this problem.

If $E_1, E_2,...,E_n$ are disjoint measurable sets, how do you show that $$m^* (A\cap [\cup E_i]) = \sum m^*(A\cap E_i)$$

I think I understand the properties of sets and their measures that make this true but I have no clue how to go about proving it.

Comment: We've never touched on pairwise disjoint sets in my class. The problem statement I have just says disjoint.

Comment: Would you be able to put in me in the right direction on this problem? because I still don't really understand.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure it will. If find it easier for me to learn things seeing the work done rather than just learning theorems and definitions.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000608/an-outer-measure-is-countable-additive-on-the-measureable-sets

Answer (score 0):

The key aspect of measurability with respect to an outer measure is that a
measurable set $E$ 'splits' a set $A$ additively in the sense that if $E$ is
measurable, we have
$m^*A = m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$ for **any** set $A$.

Let $\Delta = A \cap \cup_k E_k = \cap_k (A \cap E_k)$, where the $E_k$ are pairwise disjoint. Note that $\Delta \cap E_k = A \cap E_k$.

Then $m^* \Delta = m^* (\Delta \cap E_1) + m^*(\Delta \setminus E_1)= m^* (A \cap E_1) + m^*(\Delta \setminus E_1)$.

Now note that $\Delta \setminus E_1 =  A \cap \cup_{k\ge 2} E_k $, and repeat.

Hence $m^* (A \cap \cup_k E_k) = \sum_k m^* (A \cap E_k)$.